# Sum three text fields whose values are controlled by jqueryui sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have three jqueryui sliders that output numbers (stored in arrays) to three text fields (that have css class .add). I need the three text fields to be summed and the total to be shown in a text field (with id #amount) automatically whenever the sliders are changed. I have tried this:

```
<script>

var calcPrice = jQuery.noConflict();
calcPrice('.add').change(function () {
 var sum = 10;
      calcPrice('.add').each(function() {
        sum += Number(calcPrice(this).val());
    });
    calcPrice('#amount').val(sum);

});
</script>
```

But it only sums the three text fields if I manually type numbers into them. I also need the flexibility to change the default starting amount (var = sum 10;) whenever needed and have it display in the #amount field on page load (it does not display on page load atm).

Comment: why did you name jquery to `calcPrice` .___.

Answer (score 1):

For the UI slider, you need to use the [slider change](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) event and [value method](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value) to get the value

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.add').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10
  })
});


var calcPrice = jQuery.noConflict();
var basePrice = 10;
calcPrice('#amount').val(basePrice);
calcPrice('.add').on('slidechange', function() {
  var sum = basePrice;
  calcPrice('.add').each(function() {
    sum += Number(calcPrice(this).slider('value')) || 0;
  });
  calcPrice('#amount').val(sum);

});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="add" />
<br />
<div class="add" />
<br />
<div class="add" />
<br />
<input id="amount" />
```

Comment: I appreciate your input @Arun P Johny. Unfortunately I need to use the text fields as I described. The bigger picture (selling a configurable product) of what I am trying to do is: I have three dropdowns that show/hide a number of different jqeuryui sliders (three sliders are shown at any one time). The slider values (with min, max, and step settings) define weight while the price values for each step are stored in an array (there is also an array that stores names for each step). Since I have a large number of sliders and am using arrays it seems easier to me to use the text fields.

Comment: @DDA are use using html range element or jQuery UI slider? Can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aq12Lxqp/) to replicate your case